# ASP.NET Dropdown list :Binding More value for option

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a table with 3 columns `ID`, `Name` and `shortname`. I am binding this to a ASP.NET dropdonwlist control. I specified `DataTextField` as `ID`, `DataValueField` as `Name`.

Now the dropdown renders the list item properly and I am able to select the ID of the selected option. I want to have the short name also with the ID. Is there any way to do this? I.e. I want to read the ID, Short name and Name from the selected option of the ASP.NET dropdownlist

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ShortNameWithId
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Id, ShortName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now use the ShortNameWithId, intead of Id.
So, this would be databound to the listbox as some sort of collection (of someclass) ie List, IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Function Fld(ByVal pos As Integer, ByVal mfld As String) As String
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    For i = 1 To pos
        k = j + 1
        j = InStr(k, mfld, Chr(13))
        j = IIf(j = 0, Len(mfld) + 1, j)
    Next
    Return Mid(mfld, k, j - k)
End Function

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = Fld(1, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
    Label2.Text = Fld(2, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
End Sub
```

Or you may use:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Fld As Array
    Fld = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.Split(Chr(13))
    Label1.Text = Fld(0)
    Label2.Text = Fld(1)
End Sub
```

You can have more columns in DataValueField also.

Answer (score 0):

```
    drp.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
    {
        drp.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.ID+ "," + item.Name + "," + item.ShortName, item.ID));
    }

    //read selected text or value like this:

    string txt = drp.SelectedItem.Text;
    string val = drp.SelectedItem.Value;
```